# Server has a weak ephemeral diffie-hellman public key on Cisco ISE

Tags: wireless, cisco-ise

**Server has a weak ephemeral diffie-hellman public key** on accessing Cisco ISE portal webpage for using BYOD services and Guest internet services, This issue is mostly on Google Chrome , but we cannot control everyone to stop using chrome, and entertain huge amount of complaints.

Any way to resolve this issue of Cisco ISE ?

Comment: Using CA certificate from GoDaddy.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue with Chrome has been answered before:-

https://superuser.com/questions/966855/force-chrome-to-ignore-a-weak-ephemeral-diffie-hellman-public-key

We had a similar situation where the serveradmin guys had to regenerate AND test the certificates.

Then test in your lab environment with your network devices to iron out any bugs. There are public documents available to assist and/or place a request with TaC.

http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/how_to/HowTo-103-Implement_Cisco_ISE_Server_Side_Certificates.pdf